# Android app doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Faced with error when my simple android java parsing app isn't working. It only shows "Error" text (caught exception) instead of single element of the page. The filter is ok as app was working on other emulator, but now i can't remember the specs of that AVD.

```
package com.example.untitled5;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    static final String BLOG_URL = "[here is correct link]";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // set layout view
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // process
        try {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(getBlogStats());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("Error");
        }
    }
    protected String getBlogStats() throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        // get html document structure
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
        // selector query
        //while (!document.)
        Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select(".ttElement");
        // check results
        if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
            // get value
            result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
        }

        // return
        return result;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

```
02-18 20:34:38.021       91-130/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.untitled5/.MyActivity: +2s702ms
02-18 20:34:43.221      390-390/com.android.defcontainer D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 54% free 2537K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 46ms
02-18 20:34:47.537       91-204/system_process D/SntpClient﹕ request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

update: slightly rework the code with your hints

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    static final String BLOG_URL = "link";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // set layout view
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // async task start
        new FillText().execute();
    }
    private class FillText extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = "";

            // get html document structure
            Document document = null;
            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // selector query
            Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select(".ttElement");
            // check results
            if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
                // get value
                result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
            }

            // return
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String myText){
            super.onPostExecute(myText);
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(doInBackground());
        }
    }
}
```

now i'm getting next error:

```
02-18 23:17:26.371      688-697/com.example.untitled5 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.untitled5.MyActivity$FillText.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:40)
            at com.example.untitled5.MyActivity$FillText.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:26)
```

Comment: The error text is there for you to read. The stack trace usually points to the exact line where the error occurred. After that it's usually trivial to fix (NullPointerException is a popular one for example, where you forgot to instantiate something).

Comment: Show us the stack trace?

Comment: It's not IDE's notification of error, it's manually set text of caught exception in ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("Error"); here. I.e. app works but it can't get the data from site. Previously it worked good but with another AVD settings.

Comment: @LingWillOk Don't catch the exception. It's generally bad to catch an exception, unless you have a specific reason for doing so.

Comment: @LingWillOk Catch the exception, but print the stacktrace to see what really happens.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get() error: java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Added logcat to opost

Comment: @LingWillOk That's one reason to catch it :p. Like ZouZou said, catch it but print the stack trace yourself.

Comment: `java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol`

Comment: added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> to AndroidManifext.xml but it didn't work, still getting the error. When i'm launching the app it's not showing any errors in logcat, the java.net.SocketException appears half min after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your error could be related to delays inside of the json request in getBlogStats()

You should use an AsyncTask to fill that textview.. something like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ....

    // AsyncTask start
    new FillText().execute();

    ..

}

private class FillText extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = "";
        // get html document structure
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
        // selector query
        //while (!document.)
        Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select(".ttElement");
        // check results
        if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
            // get value
            result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
        }

        // return
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String myText) {
        super.onPostExecute(myText);

        if(!myText.equals(""))
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(myText);
    }
}
```

Bye

Comment: great thanks! One thing: Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get(); requires to handle java.IOException by throwing it, but as we overriding, i'm facing error:  java: doInBackground(java.lang.Void...) in com.example.untitled5.MyActivity.FillText cannot override doInBackground(Params...) in android.os.AsyncTask
  overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception

Comment: The error is inside "onPostExecute", you must use the return string "myText" as variable for setText method and not AsyncTask doInBackground() ;)
Use this and everything will work: ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(myText);

Comment: changed to "myText" but still get the same error. IDE also highlights document.select(".ttElement") as it may produce java.lang.NullPointerException. Deleting try catch around document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get() causes error about unhandled exception.